# bigquery update column with results from an analytical function

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset.table in Bigquery. It has return_code and response_time columns besides few other columns. I need to add a new column 'normal_abnormal' and
fill the column with value 'abnormal' if:
response_time is >= 99 percentile or
return_code starts with 4 or 5
else
fill column with 'normal';

I am trying to write a query like below but looks like I can't use UPDATE with WITH  AS.

I am new to bigquery so please bear with me.

```
WITH
  temp_table AS (
SELECT 
CASE 
   WHEN ROUND(PERCENT_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY response_time ),2)*100 >= 99 THEN 'abnormal'
   WHEN starts_with(return_code, '4') THEN 'abnormal'
   WHEN starts_with(return_code, '5') THEN 'abnormal'
   ELSE 'normal'
   END
   AS normality
FROM `access_log`)
UPDATE <=== CAn't use update here.
```

Any guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: You can add a new column directly in the **SELECT** list without using **UPDATE** .  
**SELECT *, CASE WHEN ....THEN.. ELSE .. END AS normal_abnormal FROM access_log** seems enough for your purpose.

Comment: To clarify your question, do you want your `access_log table` to be updated and have a new column? Or you just want to use CTE to just select from `access_log` with additional column "normal_abnormal" on the query select result?